# Restrict permissions when loading C function pointer from dylib

Tags: c, macos, security, dll, function-pointers

I need to load a C function pointer from a dynamic library for use in my Swift app.
The loading code doesn't have to be Swift, I just need a usable function pointer.

I can do this via `dlsym`:

```swift
let handle = dlopen(theLibrary, RTLD_NOW)
let fun = dlsym(handle, functionName)!
let casted = unsafeBitCast(unsafeBitCast(fun, to: IMP.self), to: (@convention(c)() -> Void).self)
dlclose(handle)
```

However, I'm concerned about the security of doing this. If the loaded code is being pulled from the dynamic library into my app's process, won't the loaded code have the same permissions as my app's? So, if I disabled app sandbox, couldn't the loaded code modify the users files or make network requests or worse like my app could?

I'm looking for plugin functionality here so I may not get to see the loaded dylibs actual source code, so ideally need a way to restrict the dylib's permissions to prevent possible malware running under the permissions of my app.

How can I either enforce security restrictions on a dylib prior to loading it, or lock-down loaded function pointer code?

**Edit** Craig Estey makes a very good point that even `dlopen` can be dangerous.

Comment: The TL;DR is: _don't worry be happy_. In short, **don't** load _any_ shared lib that you don't trust into your app. The lib's _init_ function can do all the damage during `dlopen`. If you must, create a separate helper program that runs the lib and works like an RPC server to your app. It is relatively easy to lower privileges but difficult to reraise them unless you're superuser. The easiest way is to change the uid to nobody but only root can do that

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question, and a very difficult one to fully address.  Most of my answer is, well first thoughts on the topic, however hopefully it will give you ideas on how to proceed.

## With Vanilla Kernels

Generally speaking once the code is linked into your binary (e.g. through dynamic loading, it will run with the permissions of your app); You would need the operating system kernel to provide some facility to mark that code "special" somehow in order to restrict the capabilities whilst you're in the context of the plugin.

### Darwin

I am not sure if Darwin kernel has the granularity of namespaces that we find e.g. under Linux (which may or may not be enough as well). However you could use end-point-security API available under OS X 11.5 or above to *monitor your self*.  The simple side-channel attack on that is the plugin would unhook you teehee.

### Linux

You would set up a new namespace, say using `setns` and spawn a thread in it after limiting its access and downgrading the context and require the plugin to communicate via an IPC channel rather than direct function calls.

## Write a kext

Bad and rather impractical idea. However you could write a kext that tracks and drops the process into a sandbox and then lifts it back up.   The only way that would work would be to have an ioctl on a special nonce (e.g. a file descriptor) that is passed from the kernel to the privileged code.  The code would then drop down to a sandbox do its job, and release the nonce (e.g. close the file) and that would lift it back up.  During this time the code will not be allowed to perform any type of code injection loading of other dlls, spawning of threads, etc. (you would have do a deep dive on possible attack vectors and close them all) that would let the plugin insert trampoline code on the return address of the stack.  Here too I would simply say spawn off a new sub-thread or a sub-process that uses IPC rather than communicating through a function call interface.

once the nonce is dropped the app is then reelevated to privileged mode.

Comment: thank you. It seems that the EndpointSecurity module is the way to go. How might I use it to say, elevate my app's process permissions after using the loaded code, or drop permissions just before?